# Format an array with date objects and show them in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an API call which returns an array of objects. Inside these objects, I have a date / timestamp which is formatted as ISO (correct me if I'm wrong).

The code below is right after my `render()` method:

```
const pickerItems = this.props.currentData.trips.map(trip => {
    return { 
        label: trip.start.timestamp, 
        value: trip.tripId 
    };
  });

  console.log(pickerItems);
```

The console log returns the following:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "label": "2019-05-24T10:12:01.123Z",
    "value": "1C8EB4E0888640ED9211CB8C563542D0",
  },
Object {
    "label": "2019-05-24T10:12:01.123Z",
    "value": "1C8EB4E0888640ED9211CB8C563542D0",
  },
]
```

My Dropdown component:

```
<RNPickerSelect items={pickerItems} />
```

How could I do the below task in most simple & efficient way?

**- Make a dropdown list where all the label (which is sent down as items) is the current date formatted as: 2019-05-24 followed by the exact time.**

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Comment: Can you also share what the RNPickerSelect already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are mapping your array, you should change ISO date to normal date and use it like the one below:

```
const pickerItems = this.props.currentData.trips.map(trip => {
      const someDay= new Date(trip.start.timestamp)
        return { 
            label: `${someDay.geyFullYear()}-{someDay.getMonth + 1}-{someDay.getDate() ${someDay.getHours()}:${someDay.getMinutes()}}`, 
            value: trip.tripId 
        };
      });

      console.log(pickerItems);
```

Comment: No problem, I just saw that you also want to time in your label and updated the answer. Good luck with project!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using the `Picker` component from **react-native** and `moment` library for formatting:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedDate}
  style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({selectedDate: itemValue})
  }>
  {props.items.map(item => <Picker.Item label={moment(item).format('YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')} value={item} />
</Picker>
```

Comment: Thanks you I combinded this solution with meDeepakJain's! Worked like a charm thanks.